# web.config causes HTTP 500 issue with virtual directory in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm fairly new to IIS so apologies if this is a basic question.

I have an IIS config serving an internal company website (php instead of asp.net).  The prod version of the website is at the 'Default Web Site' level and I've got demo and test versions of the website mapped as virtual directories.  The demo and test version are essentially copies of the prod directory. I've noticed the with the web.config copied to these VDs, I get an error 500 on the root url for the VD only.  I.E.  main website is https://mainwebsite.com and works fine but https://mainwebsite.com/demo/ doesn't work while https://mainwebsite.com/demo/index.php works fine.

The web.config file is pretty basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

    <handlers>

        </handlers>

        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

    <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:03:00" />
        </staticContent>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Moving the web.config file out of the way in the VD resolves the issue.  Even though the files are identical, I wouldn't think that the file should cause a conflict as my understanding is that IIS supports multiple web config files.

Although I have a workaround in place by renaming or deleting the file, I am wondering if there's a way to keep the file in place without it causing this error.

Comment: Turn on `detailed errors for localhost` the browse the site from IIS admin and see exactly what the issue is and add it to the question. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx Also if I were going to use PHP on my Win box I would have just used Apache with it.

Comment: Thanks, that should be helpful.  The webstack was in place before I started working here or else I'd be using apache or nginx, myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Panama Jack in the comments, I was able to resolve my issue.

I got this response with detailed errors:

```
Error Summary 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

And further down:

```
Config Error
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'value' set to 'index.php'
```

To resolve, I simply commented out this line in the web.config XML:

```
<add value="index.php" />
```

I'm sure there's a better way to approach this but for now, this gets me my answer and also how to get more info from IIS when the logs are not useful.

Comment: A better alternative is to add a <remove value="index.php" /> above the <add> tag. Then you can use the same copy of web.config in both the web site and the virtual directories.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a virtual directory to another web root
web.config will cause this (personally I think the location of this file is totally insane.. mixed with htm and images etc. )
Replicate the directory somewhere else without the web.config file/excluding it..then point the virtual directory there.. & have a task set up to copy newer files over..